# AXIOS POST extracting data from response

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, axios

I written a AXIOS using POST and GET Method using some help from youtube. The return results I have from AXIOS is response and has all the elements. How can I extract only the data like username, email...etc instead of the entire response?

The result return...
[image]

```javascript
function performGetRequest2(){
var resultElement = document.getElementById('getResult2');
var todoId = document.getElementById('todoId').value;
resultElement.innerHTML = '';

axios( {
  method: 'post',
  url:'http://localhost:8081/userget',
  data : {
    userid : todoId
  }
})
  .then(function (response) {
    
    resultElement.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    resultElement.innerHTML = generateErrorHTMLOutput(error);
  });
```

Comment: response.data.map(user => console.log(user.username)) - something like this

Comment: Usually, you want something like `resultElement.innerHTML = response.data.username`. Where do you want to put the response data?

Answer (score 1):

Try to `console.log` this way in your function

```
function performGetRequest2(){
    var resultElement = document.getElementById('getResult2');
    var todoId = document.getElementById('todoId').value;
    resultElement.innerHTML = '';

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url:'http://localhost:8081/userget',
        data : {
        userid : todoId
        }
    })
    .then(function(response){
        resultElement.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response);
        const newArray=response.data.result;

        for(let i=0;i<newArray.length;i++)
        {
            //access userid
            console.log(newArray[i].userid);
            //access username
            console.log(newArray[i].username);
            //access emai
            console.log(newArray[i].email);
            //access role
            console.log(newArray[i].role);
            //access password
            console.log(newArray[i].password);
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        resultElement.innerHTML = generateErrorHTMLOutput(error);
    }
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

To get response result:

```
response.data.result[0]
```

since the result is of array we can access it by indexing.

To get userid, username,email,role, password:

```
response.data.result[0].userid
response.data.result[0].username
response.data.result[0].email
response.data.result[0].role
response.data.result[0].password
```

To fetch all elements from the result array:

```
 response.data.result.forEach((elements)=>{
       console.log(elements.userid);
       console.log(elements.username);
       console.log(elements.email);

  })
```

DEMO:

```html
<script>

    data = {
      "result": [

        {
          "userid": "1",
          "username": "hello",
          "email": "hello@gmail.com",
          "role": "admin",
          "password": "1234"
        }
      ]

    };
    console.log(data.result[0]);
    console.log(data.result[0].userid)
    console.log(data.result[0].username)
    console.log(data.result[0].email)
    console.log(data.result[0].role)
    console.log(data.result[0].password)

     data2 = {
      "result": [

        {
          "userid": "1",
          "username": "hello",
          "email": "hello@gmail.com",
          "role": "admin",
          "password": "1234"
        },
          {
          "userid": "2",
          "username": "hello",
          "email": "hello@gmail.com",
          "role": "admin",
          "password": "1234"
        }
      ]

    };

     data2.result.forEach((elements)=>{
           console.log(elements.userid);
           console.log(elements.username);
           console.log(elements.email);
      })

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could deconstruct your object `{username}=Data.response[0]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way :

```js
{username} = data.response.result[0];
```